# Memory size exhausted when trying to run cron manually

Tags: 6, cron

On my Drupal 6 website, when I run manually cron, I get this error message.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4181580 bytes) in /dirname/includes/database.mysql-common.inc on line 34

Cron is set to automatically run every night; the last few days it wasn't running, so I tried it manually.

Where should I increase memory, in the settings.php file, in the php.ini file for PHP, or somewhere else? I'm using AWS RDS and EC2 instances.

I have this line in the settings.php file.

```php
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Comment: be sure also to see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46293/increase-memory-limit-doesnt-help-in-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-mo, which covers other possible causes and fixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is increase your PHP Memory Limit from 128M to 265M, for example adding the following line in the *settings.php* file.

```php
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')
```

For more information on other ways to change it, see [Changing PHP memory limits](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/changing-php-memory-limits).